# Amortized time for dynamic array

Tags: algorithm-analysis, arrays, amortized-analysis

I'm struggling to understand one part from the book "Cracking the coding interview".
The author states inserting an element in a dynamic array is $O(1)$ most of the time, except when the array is full and we have to reallocate.

Inserting $X$ elements take $O(2X)$ (because $\frac{X}{1} + \frac{X}{2} + \frac{x}{4} + \ldots + 1  \approx  2 X$)

I perfectly understand until this point but I don't understand second sentence:

> "Therefore, $X$ insertions take $O(2X)$ time. **The amortized time for each insertion is $O(1)$**."

How did she came to this conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

You should read more precisely the definition of [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis). As we have $X$ operations here, the time complexity of these operations should be divided by the number of operations to find the amortized complexity of the algorithm. Hence, $\frac{O(2X)}{X}$ is the amortized complexity of the insertion algorithm which is $O(1)$.

Comment: I don't think this answer is misleading. Why $\frac{(2)}{} = O(1)$? Does it come from your intuition? Please see my answer for a real mathematical proof of why is it true

Comment: @Hugues Yes. Base on the definition of the asymptotic notations, the proof is straightforward. There is no extra point there.

Answer (score 0):

From this post on [Mathematics stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3717108) :

> $\Theta(g)$ is set of functions $\left\lbrace f: \exists c_f,C_f>0, \ \exists N,\ n>N, c_fg \leqslant f \leqslant C_f g\right\rbrace$. We consider only non negative functions.
>
> There are some properties outgoing from definition: $$f \cdot \Theta(g)=\Theta(g \cdot f)$$ $$\Theta(f) + \Theta(g)=\Theta(g + f)$$ And for $g>0$ holds $\frac{\Theta(f)}{g} = \Theta \left(\frac{f}{g}\right)$

It's straightforward to demonstrate those three properties. Please let me know if you want me to add them to this answer.

Thus we can assume $\frac {O(2X)}{X} = O(\frac {2X}{X}) = O(2) = O(1)$ with $O$ <=> $\Theta$ in the context of computer science:

> "In industry (and therefore in interviews), people seem to have merge $Θ$ and $$ together. Industry's meaning of big $O$ is closer to what academics mean by $\Theta$, in that would be seen as incorrect to describe printing an array as $O(n^2)$. Industry would just say this is $O(n)$. "
>   - Cracking the Coding Interview

Comment: I have no idea what $O\iff \Theta$ means. $f=O(g)$ is definitely not equivalent to $f=\Theta(g)$. The only meaning I can attribute to this statement is that for practical applications you are usually interested in upper bounds on the complexity, and lower bounds or tight bounds (reflected by $\Theta$) are usually more theory oriented. Still, this is a very bad sentence.

Comment: @Ariel Sorry if it's unclear.
From the book I was refering to: "In industry (and therefore in interviews), people seem to have merge $\Theta$ and $O$ together. Industry's meaning of big O is closer to what academics mean by $\Theta$, in that would be seen as incorrect to describe printing an array as $O(n^2). Industry would just say this is O(N).